# How to understand the data structure of Python Linked List in Leetcode

Tags: python, data-structures, linked-list

I am really confused by the Python linked list data structure used in Leetcode. I am not sure if the problem is caused by the specific ListNode structure created by Leetcode, or I have some misunderstanding about Python. For example, the following piece of code is simple and self-explained:

```
# class ListNode:
#     def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.next = next
def main():
    # Instantiate a linked list 1 -> 2 -> 3
    a = ListNode(1)
    b = ListNode(2)
    c = ListNode(3)
    a.next = b
    b.next = c
    print(a) # a is 1 -> 2 -> 3
    b.next = None
    print(a) # a is 1 -> 2
    b = None
    print(a) # a is still 1 -> 2, why changing b doesn't change a, but changing b.next changes a???
```

Suppose I have a linked list a -> b -> c. When I set `b.next = None`, `a.next.next = None`. However, the thing that confuses me is that, when I set `b = None`, `a.next` doesn't become `None`.What's the difference between operating `b` and `b.next`, why they have different influence on `a`?

Comment: You don't really have a linked list data structure. You have a `ListNode` class whose instances can be *used* to build a linked list, but no class that encapsulates the idea of a linked list and provides methods like `append`, `insert`, `find`, `remove`, etc.

Comment: As for your actual question, read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html. Assignments never change existing values, only the *name* being assigned to.

Comment: Yeah, so maybe the question is about the `ListNode` structure? I just don't understand why changing `b` and `b.next` has different influence `a`

Comment: Because assigning to `b` has no effect on other references to the same object.

Comment: The way to read the first binding `a.next = b` is "make `a.next` point at the same thing `b` is pointing at currently", and then the second binding `b = None` should be read as "make b point to nothing now". Read this way, it makes it a bit more clear that the second binding has no influence on `a.next`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Drawing diagrams helps.  Here's your linked list:

```
[   ]
  |
  v
[   ]
  |
  V
[   ]
  |
  V
 None
```

Each arrow leading from a box represents the `next` attribute of that node.

Here are the three variables `a`, `b`, and `c`:

```
         [   ] <-- a
           |
           v
         [   ] <-- b
           |
           V
         [   ] <-- c
           |
           V
          None
```

Each of these variables also points to a particular node.

If you say `b.next = None`, the `next` attribute of the node referenced by `b` is modified, like this:

```
         [   ] <-- a
           |
           v
None <-- [   ] <-- b


         [   ] <-- c
           |
           V
          None
```

This modifies the structure of the list.  If you just set `b` itself to a different value, though, this is what happens:

```
         [   ] <-- a
           |
           v
None <-- [   ]     b --> None


         [   ] <-- c
           |
           V
          None
```

You changed `b`, but the node that `b` used to point to stays right where it was.  Note that this is similar to how the `c` node continued to exist even after you set `b.next = None`.

Answer (score 1):

Python doesn't have double pointers e.g. `**x`

```
b.next = c
print(a) # a is 1 -> 2 -> 3
b.next = None
```

E.g. in above, it doesn't mean `c is None`

When `a.next` is `b`, if you change `a.next.next` you are effectively changing `b.next`

But if you change `a.next` to `None`, it will not set `b` to `None`

Edit:

Also when you set `b = None` but `a.next` still points `ListNode(2)`

Answer (score 1):

`a` is a reference to `ListNode(1)`. There are *two* references to `ListNode(2)`: the one stored in `ListNode(1)`, referenced as `a.next`, and one in `b`.

Think of these references as arrows.

When you make the assignment `b = None`, you simply removing the *arrow* from `b` to `ListNode(2)` and replacing it with an arrow from `b` to `None`. This has no effect on the arrow from `ListNode(1)` to `ListNode(2)`.

If you were instead to make a change to, say, `ListNode(3)`, then that change would be visible from all *three* references to it: `a.next.next`, `b.next`, and `c`.

Note that an assignment like `b.next = ...` is very different from `b = ...`. The latter is a "true" assignment, while the former is special syntax for a function call like `setattr(b, 'next', ...)`. It modifies some object (specifically, the value of once of its attributes) in place, rather than just making a name point to something else.